# ow can I assemble a camera that reads a sequence of numbers? with react-native

Tags: java, android, react-native, numbers

Is there any library that reads sequence of numbers for example on a paper has 123456789

I want to get only the first 3 digits with the camera, I didn't even find a library that does that

I tried to use react-native-camera with frame but I was not successful, I also tried to find java codes to put directly in react-native and call the function

If anyone knows where I can start, thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you missed that but react-native-camera is deprecated since a long time for react-native-vision-camera which is really powerful. You can see in the doc that you can add frame processors to it.

"I didn't even find a library that does that" => It would not be really a surprise to not find an open source library which combine a camera with image recognition for you.

But cause it is your lucky day someone developed the frame processors you searched for:
https://github.com/aarongrider/vision-camera-ocr

Have fun with it!

Comment: When I say I haven't found one I really mean not having found one, I'll take a look at that library thanks,

I'll come back later to say if it helped me